# How to use a dynamic variable in html command <a href=" "></a> which should change as per the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a .html file which contains a global variable(var cape_name;)which might contain values:
1.cape_name=TIDA-550;
2.cape_name=TIDA-560;

Now, I have two files corresponding to both values: (TIDA-550.js and TIDA-550.html) and  (TIDA-560.js and TIDA-560.html ).Both .js files are running in background and are waiting for the corresponding .html files to be loaded.

I have another main.html and main.js files.  In main.html, I want to put a link to load TIDA-550.html or TIDA-560.html depending on cape_name value.(cape_name.html).

For example: In below line, I want to use 'cape_name' dynamically depending on its value and then load the corresponding html file.

```
<a href="http://137.167.189.23:8085/var/lib/cloud9/cape_name.html" target="blank">Load Cape on 0x54</a>
```

Any suggestions how to do it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add id to the link like:

```
<a id="link" target="blank">Load Cape on 0x54</a>
```

and add href dynamically:

```
$('#link').attr('href', 'http://137.167.189.23:8085/var/lib/cloud9/' + cape_name + '.html');
```

you may need to wrap that in `$(function() { });` so it's executed when DOM is ready.